# Test that the imageview has set the uri correctly

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I have an activity that will receive an intent containing an uri in the onActivityResult method,after the user takes a picture.And after that the imageview are supposed to set that uri using setImageUri method.
How do I write a test that ensures the imageview has set the uri accordingly?Should I use a real uri for test or just any String?

Comment: I believe you are setting Image to imageview via URI, if yes you should use real URI(local) for sure.

Comment: So if I change my testing device,I need to find another real uri that actually contains an image and modify my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I use an image from resource and convert it to URI to test my code:

```java
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.idreamsglobal.idreams/" + R.drawable.arrow)
```